# QR data in incorrect format

Tags: c#, barcode, qr-code, zxing

I am using C# to create a backend service to read and interpret QR codes and return the string data. To my limited QR knowledge, there is a checksum embedded in the code disallowing erroneous data interpretation from an image, so I went on to assume that this is a encoding issue in the libs I am using because the two different libraries I use deliver these two different results.

**Correct:**

```
{"uqr":1,"tp":1,"nme”:”Test AB”,”cid":"556036-2138","iref”:”12345678912341”,”ddt":"20140901”,”due”:633.56,”pt":"BG","acc”:”5110-8348”}
```

**Wrong:**

```
{"uqr":1,"tp":1,"nmeâ?:â?Test ABâ?,â?cid":"556036-2138","irefâ?:â?12345678912341â?,â?ddt":"20140901â?,â?dueâ?:633.56,â?pt":"BG","accâ?:â?5110-8348â?}
```

The wrong one is from the **barcodelib** (`barcodelib.com`) and the correct one is from the OpenSource lib **ZXing** (`zxingnet.codeplex.com`).

The strange part however, is that the **barcodelib** which generally is better at detecting and interpreting QR codes (with shadows and from different angles) sometimes returns correctly (see below) formatted jsons as well.

**Example of correct formatting from barcodelib:**

```
{"uqr":1,"tp":1,"nme":"Test AB","cid":"556357-0430","iref":"52654","ddt":"20130524","due":2250,"pt":"BG","acc":"881-8383"}
```

How can it differ? If it was a encoding error, why isn´t it consistent? Can the QR data be interpreted erroneously after all?

**UPDATE**

As stated in comment below; the first (correct one) is not correct either since the double quotes are not regular ASCII format double quotes.

BarcodeLib code:

```
public override string GetQRData()
{
    var retVal = string.Empty;
    var settings = new OptimizeSetting();
    var results = BarcodeReader.read(ImageUrl, BarcodeReader.QRCODE, settings);
    return results.Aggregate(retVal, (current, result) => current + result);
}
```

ZXing code:

```
public override string GetQRData()
{
    var retVal = string.Empty;

    IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
    var barcodeBitmap = new Bitmap(ImageUrl);
    var result = reader.Decode(barcodeBitmap);
    if (result != null)
        retVal += result.Text;

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Your "correct" first version isn't valid JSON. Only regular ASCII double quotes are permitted as JSON property/string value endpoints. It would also help if you'd show the code you're using in each case.

Comment: Very true, I did not notice the double quote error. Updated answer with code.

Comment: Your input data, i.e. the data encoded in the QR code is wrong. Both libraries try their best to decode what's there, but both return exactly what's in the input: a [Unicode closing double quote](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm). Both `â?` and `”` represent this character. So the person who pasted the JSON in the QR image generator did so from a rich text editor, or whatever, causing the plain old double quotes (`"`) to be replaced with the fancy ones. The problem is not in your code or in the libraries, but in your data.

Comment: My input are images, can you explain further how they are _'wrong'_ ? Note that other QR readers like the one in AV Foundation reads the QR codes accurately.

Comment: Look; it is (caveat: as far as I know) impossible for a regular double quote (`"`, or Unicode code point 0x22), written as QR code, to be interpreted as `”` or Unicode code point 0x201D. Something is going wrong while **encoding** this value, which is proven by both libraries returning a character that goes way beyond ASCII (code point > 127) (case 1) and returning two characters (`â?`, case 2). Test **the same** image in AV Foundation and you'll see it either also returns garbage, or tries to correct common mistakes. Your first "correct" example is also wrong.

Comment: If you do a base64 coding of your data before you build the QR codes then you have a safeguard against this kind of encoding errors since base64 is ascii only. But to do that you must have control of the QR code generation.

Comment: Well, QR codes can contain various character sets including ISO 8859-1 UTF-8 (recommended) and even Kanji. It can use double-byte storage for a character and probably encode the french double-quotes just fine.. - Crazy: They have to  __guess__ what they read, as there are __no__ indicator characters in the code to tell them the character set used!

Comment: @TaW I don't know if that was a response to my comment. I'm not saying a QR code can't contain > ASCII characters, I'm saying that this one **does**, hence it not being valid JSON input to begin with. Garbage in, garbage out, so to say.